# Return javascript with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

A developer recently told me I could make ajax requests to php pages, have them return javascript methods and then have the client execute those methods. How is this done? A link to a relevant resources would be great too.

**Edit**

5 years wiser, I would now try pretty hard never to do this. Any mechanism of this kind opens too much risk of [cross-site scripting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). It's far safer to disable all inline javascript using [appropriate headers](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#bonus-rule-2-implement-content-security-policy), and find another way to achieve the desired functionality. If dynamically generated scripts are really required, they can be assembled on the server and included as external scripts:

```
<script src=/dynamic-script.php?param1=blah&param2=ayyylmao></script>
```

In this example dynamic-script.php would use the parameters passed to it to generate the required javascript.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for.

http://solutoire.com/2008/06/12/sending-javascript-functions-over-json/

Comment: Doesn't seem to be what I need. I want to know how to execute the javascript that is returned.

Comment: No need for ajax. Just dynamically create a `<script>` element pointing to your PHP script and insert it in your DOM.

Comment: What is the value of the server sending the client javascript functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example could be done with jQuery (a javascript library).

If you call an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"phpfile.php",
    type:"post",
    data: {id: 4},
    async:true,
    success: function(data) {
        $("div").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

and in the phpfile.php you `echo` some javascript code it can be executed:

```
<?php
echo "
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(\"#someDiv\").click(function() {
        alert(\"#someDiv clicked\");
    });
});
</script> ";
?>
```